# check if datetime from sql is today

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I have a date returned from an sql query (a datetime type field) and want to compare it to today's date in PHP. I have consulted php manual and there are many ways to do it. I finally came up with a solution comparing strings, but I would like to know if there are either any 'better' (best practice), cleaner or faster ways to do it. This is my solution:

```
// $sql_returned_date='2008-10-17 11:20:04'

 $today = new DateTime("now");
 $f_today=$today->format('Y-m-d'); //formated today = '2011-03-09'
 $sql_date=substr($sql_returned_date,0,9); //I get substring '2008-10-17'
 if($f_today==$sql_date)
 {
    echo "yes,it's today";
 }else{
    echo "no, it's not";
 }
```

thanks

Comment: Just use date('Y-m-d') instead of $today = new DateTime("now"); $f_today=$today->format('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seriously guys?

```
//$mysql_date_string= '2013-09-20' OR '2013-09-20 12:30:23', for example

$my_date = new DateTime($mysql_date_string);

if($my_date->format('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-d')) {
    //it's today, let's make ginger snaps
}
```

Comment: This dude should get his upvote a lot more people. This is the way to go.

Comment: yes, the best one I think - but a bracket is missing before the opening curly bracket

Answer (score 5):

You could factor this into the data returned from your database query:

```
SELECT `DateOnDB`,
       DATE(`DateOnDB`) = DATE(CURDATE()) AS isToday
  FROM `dbTable`
```

and simply use PHP to test the value of the isToday column

Comment: By far the cleanest solution out of all the other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have three solutions :

- Working with strings, like you are doing ; which seems like a solution *that works* ; even if it doesn't *feel clean*.
- Working with timestamps, using `strtotime()` and `time()` ; which is a bad idea : [UNIX Timestamps](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Unix_time) only work for dates that are greater than 1970 and lower than 2038
- Working with `DateTime` everywhere ; which would both work and *feel clean*.

If I need to make any calculation on the PHP-side, I would probably go with the third solution -- but the first one would be OK in most cases, I suppose.

As a sidenote : instead of formating your date to `Y-m-d`, you could check if it's :

- Greater of equal than today
- Less than tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

1. If SQL returned date is in this format 2011-03-09 (*date format without timing*),

   ```
   $sqlret = "2011-03-05";

   $curdate = date('Y-m-d');

   echo $diff = strtotime($curdate) - strtotime($sqlret);

   echo $no_diff = $diff/(60*60*24);
   ```
2. If the date with time like:

   ```
   $sqlret = "2011-03-05 12:05:05",
   ```

   Just make your current date format also like that:

   ```
   $curdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   ```
3. If it doesn't satisfies your need, ask your question with some example.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me for being a question-digger, but I was trying to achieve the same thing, and I found a simple solution - if you want to select only rows with today's date you can do :

```
WHERE DATE(datetime_column)=CURDATE()
```

in your mySQL query syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use new DateTime php Object that way.

```
      $date1 = new DateTime('2012-01-21');     
      $date2  = new DateTime ( 'now');
      $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
        if( $interval->format('%R%a ') == 0){
            echo 'it s today';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that:

```
# SQL
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_col, "%Y-%m-%d") AS created_at FROM table

# PHP
if ( date('Y-m-d') == $sql_date ) { // assuming $sql_date is SQL's created_at
    echo 'today';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = //your timestamp
$start = mktime(0,0,0,date("j"),date("n"),date("Y"));
$end = mktime(23,59,0,date("j"),date("n"),date("Y"));

if($time  > $start && $time < $end){
 //is today
}
```